# How to retrieve friends profile data using the Google Api Rest?

Tags: google-plus, google-people-api

I need retrieve from friends profile data using google api rest. i have read the documentation for google + api and the [list method is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/). right now google recommend to use people contact api for retrieve friends data. However, the data returned by this method are about contact information. I need information about the profile google plus. (email, photo, names).

Btw, the google plus api has the get method, this retrieve information about google + profile according to userId. If I could have a list of all my userId's friends, maybe with this method I could retrieve the information about profile google plus.

How can I retrieve friends information from google plus profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the google account ID, you can retrieve the Profile info using Google People API. See the example in the docs [Get the person for a Google Account](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/read-people#get-the-person-for-a-google-account).

Also while the People API ListConnections method returns contacts, it will also return profiles linked to the contacts.

If you specifically are asking for a way to list all your G+ friends, unfortunately there isn't a way to get that data since the G+ list method is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks Amos, it's a shame that list method from Google + API is deprecated.